# How to ensure that a bunch of asynchronous function calls occur only after another bunch of asynchronous function calls are complete?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am new to JavaScript and I think what I am trying to do can be solved using Promises but after reading the Mozilla documentation I am unable to figure out how to achieve this.

Let me demonstrate what I am trying to achieve with the following code.

```
// file demo.js
function async_print(message, seconds)
{
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(message, '(' + seconds + ' s)')
    }, seconds * 1000);
}

// First execute the following three asynchronously
async_print('foo', 1)
async_print('foo', 2)
async_print('foo', 3)

// Then execute the following three asynchronously
async_print('bar', 1)
async_print('bar', 2)
async_print('bar', 3)

// Then execute the following three asynchronously
async_print('baz', 1)
async_print('baz', 2)
async_print('baz', 3)
```

I get the following output.

```
$ node demo.js 
foo (1 s)
bar (1 s)
baz (1 s)
foo (2 s)
bar (2 s)
baz (2 s)
foo (3 s)
bar (3 s)
baz (3 s)
```

Also, see JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/3kdwy46r/

My intention is documented as comments in the code. I want all the 'foo' statements to be executed first. The 'bar' statements should be executed only after the 'foo' statements have completed. The 'baz' statements should be execued only after the 'bar' statements have completed. This means the output should look like this.

```
foo (1 s)
foo (2 s)
foo (3 s)
bar (1 s)
bar (2 s)
bar (3 s)
baz (1 s)
baz (2 s)
baz (3 s)
```

Is this something that can be done conveniently in JavaScript or node without depending on third party libraries? For example, can JavaScript Promise help here? I understand that I may have to modify the `async_print` function signature or wrap it around something else in order to pass callbacks that can be invoked to indicate completion of the function. I am okay with such modifications. I basically need to know how to get a job like this done.

Could you please provide a complete code sample that does this, so that I can use it to learn how to do such things in JavaScript?

Comment: CPS and promises are the two ways you can do this, and generators can help in ES6, and async/await coming in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something that is best suited for promises, `Promise.all()` and promise chaining.  Here's a snippet that you can run in a modern browser to see the output:

```js
    // return a promise from this async function that is resolved when done 
    function async_print(message, seconds) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                resolve();
            }, seconds * 1000);
        }).then(function() {
            log(message, '(' + seconds + ' s)')
        });
    }
    
    Promise.all([async_print('foo', 1), async_print('foo', 2), async_print('foo', 3)]).then(function() {
       return Promise.all([async_print('bar', 1), async_print('bar', 2), async_print('bar', 3)]);
    }).then(function() {
       return Promise.all([async_print('baz', 1), async_print('baz', 2), async_print('baz', 3)]);
    }).then(function() {
        // everything done here
    });

    function log(x,y) {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = x;
        if (arguments.length > 1) {
            div.innerHTML += y;
        }
        document.body.appendChild(div);
    }
```

The general idea is:

1. You change `async_print()` so it returns a promise that is resolved when the async operation is done.
2. You use `Promise.all()` to tell you when a group of `async_print()` statements are all done.
3. You use then `.then()` handler from `Promise.all()` to trigger the next group of actions (when all the prior ones are done).
4. You return the next `Promise.all()` in order to chain them together so the groups happen in sequence.

Comment: You should put the `log(…)` in a `then` callback (not in the promisify-`setTimeout`-callback) as it might throw

Comment: @Bergi - change made as suggested.